# Як правильно "телефонувати з іншого номера" чи "з іншого номеру"?

Tags: іменники, родовий-відмінок

Скажіть, будь ласка, як правильно *телефонувати з іншого номера* чи *з іншого номеру*. Наприклад,

> Я зателефоную тобі з іншого номер**а**.
>
> Я зателефоную тобі з іншого номер**у**.

Незалежно від того як правильно, поясніть, будь ласка, чому так, а не так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Це доволі легко перевірити за словником  (наприклад: [«Словники української мови»](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=61344&page=1961) в 20 томах і [«Словники України онлайн»](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) від УМІФ) — вважається, що слово *номер* в усіх значеннях у родовому відмінку має закінчення *-а*.

Чому так, пояснити доволі важко. Правила вибору між *-а* і *-у* в закінченнях родового відмінка доволі складні, неконкретні й час від часу змінюються (зокрема є група назв міст, яким правопис 2015 рекомендував давати закінчення *-а*, а правопис 2019 – закінчення *-у*). Загальна тенденція, на мій погляд, полягає в тому, що «конкретніші» речі тяжіють до *-а*, а «абстрактніші» — до *-у* (однак ця тенденція не абсолютна), тому я не здивуюся, якщо колись казатимуть і «нема номеру», однак наразі *номер* підпадає під [§ 82.2.1.1.2.в правопису 2019](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=88):

> Закінчення -а (у твердій та мішаній групах), -я (у м’якій групі) мають іменники чол. роду: <…> Назви  неістот  у  звичайній  та  зменшено-пестливій  формі,  що  позначають конкретні предмети, зокрема: <…> **терміни  іншомовного  походження,  які  позначають**  предмети, структурні  елементи,  геометричні  тіла  та  їхні  частини,  **математичні**, лінгвістичні  **поняття**: а́тома, ве́ктора, елеме́нта, еліпсо́їда, інтегра́ла, като́да, ква́рка, квадра́та, коефіціє́нта, ко́нуса, ко́синуса, цилі́ндра; а́фікса, інтерфі́кса, локати́ва, пре́фікса, су́фіксата   ін.,   але си́нтаксису, фразеологі́зму (про інші категорії термінів див. п. 2)

(У [§ 48.2.є правопису 2015](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par48p2ye) те саме написано більш поверхнево: «терміни іншомовного походження, які означають елементи будови чогось, конкретні предмети, геометричні фігури та їх частини: атома, катода, конуса, радіуса, ромба, сегмента, сектора, синуса, шківа тощо, а також українські за походженням суфіксальні слова-терміни: відмінка, додатка, займенника, знаменника, іменника, трикутника, чисельника, числівника тощо; але: виду, роду, також синтаксису, складу, способу (про інші категорії термінів див. п. 3)» — тут поєднано те, що в новішому правописі стало окремими пунктами § 82.2.1.1.2.в і § 82.2.1.1.2.г.)